# How to deal with "package not found" after trying to install pycrpto and the module that can't be seen

Tags: python, ubuntu-core, pip

I was trying to run Ubuntu shell on my windows and now I'm stuck with this error when I install  `pycrypto`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pip._internal import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 15, in <module>
    from distutils.util import strtobool
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.util'
```

I tried to install the module but it says it can't find the package.